# Find a sequence of linear transformations of $\mathbb{P} ^{2}$ whose composition transforms $\frac{1}{4} x ^{2} + y ^{2} = z ^{2}$ to $zy=x^2$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, linear-transformations, conic-sections, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry

Find a sequence of linear transformations of $\mathbb{P} ^{2}$ whose composition transforms the ellipse $\frac{1}{4} x ^{2} + y ^{2} = z ^{2}$ to the parabola $zy=x^2$.

$P^2$ is projective plane.

I think if I let $x=a_1x+b_1y+c_1z, y=a_2x+b_2y+c_2z, z=a_3x+b_3y+c_3z$ and then plug in the ellipse equation to solve for $a_i,b_i,c_i (i=1,2,3)$, I will get the answer. It's a lot of work and I will not get a sequence of transformation unless I decompose the matrix.

I tried to map $[1:0:1] {\mapsto} [1:0:0] $ and $[0:1:1]{\mapsto}[0:1:0]$. All of these points are in the projective plane. Both$[1:0:0]$ and$[0:1:0]$ are points in the parabpla at infinity. But I just got $z^2+2xy+2xz+2yz=0$. I didn't know how to do the next step because it seemed that it's impossible to transform $z^2+2xy+2xz+2yz=0$ to $zy=x^2$. It still needed a bunch of work.

Does there exists any simple method to get the sequence of transformation?

Comment: Don't understand exactly what you are required to do, but suppose 
it has something to do with the rewriting the equations as:
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \frac{1}
{4}x^{\,2}  + y^{\,2}  = z^{\,2} \quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left( {\frac{x}
{{2z}}} \right)^{\,2}  + \left( {\frac{y}
{z}} \right)^{\,2}  = 1 \hfill \\
  zy = x^{\,2} \quad  \Rightarrow \quad \frac{y}
{z} = 4\left( {\frac{x}
{{2z}}} \right)^{\,2}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$

Comment: @GCab Find a sequence of linear transformation to transform $\frac{1}{4} x ^{2} + y ^{2} = z ^{2}$ to $zy=x^2$

Comment: If it is so, then *KReiser*'s answer is all what you need. But you cannot talk of ellipse and parabola, and what is the use of $\mathbb{P} ^{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by putting $z$ and $y$ on the same side of the original equation to get $\frac{1}{4}x^2=z^2-y^2$. Note that the RHS factors as $(z-y)(z+y)$. Set your new $z$ to be $z-y$ and your new $y$ to be $z+y$, while letting your new $x$ be $2x$. Now you have $zy=x^2$ and you're done.